# Can I make a reasonable approximation of pink and brown noise by applying WebAudio built-in filters to white noise?

Tags: signal-processing, web-audio-api

I want to generate white, pink and brown noise in a web app and found [this example](https://noisehack.com/generate-noise-web-audio-api/). It looks good, but converting white to pink (especially) or brown in Javascript could use a lot of CPU power. Presumably WebAudio's built-in filters are implemented in native code so could be more efficient. Can BiquadFilterNode or IIRFilterNode provide a reasonable approximation? Or are they more complicated anyway, so unlikely to make any efficiency gains?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use an IIRFilterNode or (several?) BiquadFilterNodes to implement the pink noise filter.  You'll have to figure out how to express the given equations into the equivalent IIRFilterNode equations.  If that doesn't work, you'll need to find the frequency response and use some tool to approximate that response using an IIRFilterNode.